# Drupal regions not showing in admin

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've updated my theme info file with regions but they are not showing in the block admin page

/admin/build/block/list/

I have cleared all my caches but that doesn't seem to do anything.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are they not showing in the list of regions in the center of the block admin page, not showing the yellow highlighted regions themselves, or neither?

Comment: Could you post your info file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your page.tpl.php file may not be getting read. Are you maybe doing a sub-theme and the base theme's page.tpl.php is being read for some reason?

Comment: Just looked at the base theme and you're right.   Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Find out another tidbt, the theme that is set as the administrator theme is the one that gets its .info file used.   Still haven't figure out how to fix the underlying problem but I got around it by switching admin themes.

Answer (score 0):

By default, your theme .info file doesn't need to list regions, if you are planning to use the default regions.

However, as soon as you want to add a custom region, you need to list all default regions in your theme .info, and your custom region as well.

So make sure that not only your new region is defined in your info file, but all the default Drupal regions.

Read this for a more detailed explanation : http://mydrupalblog.lhmdesign.com/creating-custom-regions-drupal-6-themes

Answer (score 0):

You also have to print the new regions in page.tpl.php.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I do have the region printable though.